# Have <iframe> grow with growing element without overlapping it on pure CSS

Tags: css, iframe

I was hoping anyone could assist me with the following issue. As the title mentions, im trying to make an iframe show on hover of another element and grow with it, issue im having is the iframe shows very fast and displays outside of its parent...see the following:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
       <div class='coolbtn'>
           <h1 class='top'><span class="pictogram">)</span>Policy #142545</h1>
           <p>Google.com</p>
            <p>https://www.google.com"</p>
            <br>
            <iframe id="source" src="http://jsfiddle.net"></iframe>

       </div>
 </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EajKf/1284/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put overflow:hidden for the parent and it will hide the overflow during the transition.

```
.coolbtn {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EajKf/1286/)

Comment: Lol i figured it would be something simple, but i guess got stuck in one of those moments, were nothing makes sense anymore :) Thanks a lot. Cheers